# Get mouse position in fabric.js while moving

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events, fabricjs

I'd like to get the mouse position while moving.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) 
{
    getMouse(e);
});
function getMouse(e) 

{
    console.log(e.e.clientX,e.e.clientY);
}
```

```css
canvas 
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
```

This gets me the position of the mouse when I click. How do I get mouse position while moving the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

A quick peek at [Canvas docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) suggest replacing `mouse:up` with `mouse:move` should be what you're after.

See it working:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

const getMouse = ({ e }) => {
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

canvas.on('mouse:move', getMouse);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
```